# How to emulate linux dir on windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows

On my Windows 7 PC I need to have a linux like dir, for example, "/opt/test/" that points to the real physical dir "C:/Test". Is this possible? If so, would it be through a symbolic link?

Edit: I have a properties file that is used on a Java application by using the Properties class of java.utils. Several properties values are linux file paths and my goal is to use those paths without having to change them on the properties files.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achive what I wanted by creating symlinks with the mklink command. For example, to simulate the /opt/test file path I just had to create a dir named opt on c:/ and then, inside c:/opt I created a symlink Test that points to C:/Test.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell, I believe the set-alias command will suffice for your needs. You can also integrate the aliases you need created into your PowerShell profile, so they'll load up every time you start it.